# What is $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ where $K = k(V)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K=k(V)$ be the function field of a nonsingular projective variety $V$ over an algebraically closed field $k$. What are the $x_i$'s of an element
$$\mathbf{x} = [x_0:...:x_n] \in \mathbb{P}^n(K)?$$
I'm asking this because I realised I couldn't make sense of the following excerpt

> For a homogeneous polynomial $Q \in K[X_0,...,X_n]$, fix a prime divisor $\mathfrak{p}$ of $V$. Then for each $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{P}^n(K) \setminus \{Q = 0\}$, one can define the order $\mathrm{ord}_\mathfrak{p}(Q(\mathbf{x}))$.

My guess is that each $x_i$ is a rational function on $V$ but I'm not sure what the evaluation $Q(\mathbf{x})$ means. Could anyone give an explicit example that can illustrate this idea clearly?

Comment: The $x_i$‘s are elements of the field $k$. For $Q(x)$ you essentially just plug in any representative into the polynomial $Q$.

Comment: @QiZhu So there is no difference between $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ and $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$?

Comment: I think it should be $x_j \in K$, not $\in k$. $Q$ is a polynomial over $K$, then for an $(n+1)$-tuple $\mathbf x \in K^{n+1}$, $Q (\mathbf x)$ is naturally the evaluation $Q(x_0, \dots, x_n)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $K$ and not $k$.

Comment: @QiZhu ok I got it thanks.